# Why is react-redux creating multiple states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Not a problem as such, just a question.

I'm using React-Redux to handle my application state. I've connected my highest level component, named `Academy`, with `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` etc.

I then have a child component, `SlideOverBar` which is connected only for dispatches with the following line of code:

`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SlideOverBar);`

Now, everything works as expected, but for some reason in my React Developer Tools, the `SlideOverBar` component has a full copy of the state. This state is never updated, but I'm concerned in case it may cause any issues down the line. Can anyone tell me - is this normal and if not, what can I do about it.

To clarify, here's some screenshots from the Developer tools:

The Academy component, where the state updates when required. You can see that the `workshopSelection.selectedLevel` piece of state has been updated from `null` to `4`, which is as it should be:

[image: Academy Component]

The `SlideOverBar` component. The state here is a copy of the state in `Academy`. It never updates (which is good - the `Academy` state should be controlling the application) but I don't understand why it is there in the first place. The `mapStateToProps` value on this component is set to `null`.

[image: SlideOverBar Component]

**UPDATE**

Here's the full code for each of the components.

Academy:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {showSlideOver, hideSlideOver} from '../../data/actions/actions';
import styles from '../../cssPartials/Academy.css';
import TopBar from './../TopBar';
import SideMenu from './../SideMenu';
import ViewPort from './../ViewPort';
import SlideOverBar from '../slideOver/SlideOverBar';

class Academy extends Component {

    render(){

        return (
            <div className={styles.academy}>
                <div className={styles.spacer} />
                <TopBar />
                <div className={styles.container}>
                    <SideMenu />
                    <ViewPort>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </ViewPort>
                </div>
                <SlideOverBar slideOver={this.props.slideOver}
                              workshopSelection={this.props.workshopSelection}
                              slideOverAction={this.props.hideSlideOver}
                />
            </div>
        )   
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        slideOver: state.slideOver,
        workshopSelection: state.workshopSelection
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ showSlideOver: showSlideOver, hideSlideOver: hideSlideOver }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Academy);
```

SlideOverBar:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import styles from '../../cssPartials/slideOverBar.css';
import SlideOverBarTop from './SlideOverBarTop';
import NewWorkshop from './NewWorkshop';
import EditWorkshop from './EditWorkshop';
import UploadSlides from './UploadSlides';
import UploadWorkbook from './UploadWorkbook';
import ViewWorkbook from './ViewWorkbook';
import UploadResources from './UploadResources';
import ViewResources from './ViewResources';
import constants from '../../data/constants.js';
import {chooseLevel, chooseVenue, chooseUnit, showCourses, dayCounter, chooseTutor, resetWorkshops } from '../../data/actions/actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class SlideOverBar extends Component {

    loadContent(testCase){
        switch (testCase){
            case constants.ADD_WORKSHOP:
                return <NewWorkshop properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.EDIT_WORKSHOP:
                return <EditWorkshop properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.UPLOAD_SLIDES:
                return <UploadSlides properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.UPLOAD_WORKBOOK:
                return <UploadWorkbook properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.VIEW_WORKBOOK:
                return <ViewWorkbook properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.UPLOAD_RESOURCES:
                return <UploadResources properties = {this.props} />
            case constants.VIEW_RESOURCES:
                return <ViewResources properties = {this.props} />
            default:
                return <div>Uh oh, something went wrong!</div>
        }

    }

    render(){       
        return (
            <div className={this.props.slideOver.visible ? `${styles.slideOverBar} ${styles.visible}`
                                    : styles.slideOverBar }>
                <SlideOverBarTop slideOverAction = {this.props.slideOverAction}
                                 reset = {this.props.resetWorkshops}
                                 title = {this.props.slideOver.content} />
                {this.loadContent(this.props.slideOver.content)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({ chooseLevel, chooseVenue, chooseUnit, showCourses, chooseTutor, resetWorkshops }, dispatch);
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SlideOverBar);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste some code please? Without looking at the code, it is difficult for us to say what the issue is.

Comment: By the way, when you expand Connect(SlideOverBar) and inspect SlideOverBar what do you see? You are looking at the State for connect that would have all the state, not the ones passed to the actual component.

Comment: Code added. When I expand Connect(SlideOverBar) I just see the SlideOverBar component with a list of props - no state, context or anything else

Comment: I'm just concerned that when inspecting the Connect(SlideOverBar) there appears to be a duplicate store. As I said, the application works fine and this duplicate store doesn't appear to update at all, but I'm trying to find out if this is normal or if there could be a potential issue or conflict further down the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to worry about.  You are just seeing the HOC `Connect` that is used by the `connect` function.  This component uses the whole store `context` underneath.  This is just a reference to the store and is not copying.

If you checkout out [this line of code from connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L92), you can see that the `Connect` component is pulling the full store and setting it as its `state`.

```
const storeState = this.store.getState()
this.state = { storeState }
```

This allows the `Connect` component to then bind particular `store` values in with `mapStateToProps`.  But since you are passing `null` it will default to:

```
const defaultMapStateToProps = state => ({})
```

Comment: That's great, thank you - has put my mind at ease, I had horrible visions of seemingly random changes to state later on!